# Proper Way of Adding jQuery to a Tizen Web App for Wearables?

Tags: jquery, tizen, tizen-web-app

I've created a new *Tizen web app for wearables* following the [official *Getting Started* guide](https://developer.tizen.org/development/getting-started/web-application/creating-your-first-tizen-application). Then, I've searched the web for hours for what how to *properly* add jQuery to that project. I've read multiple times that the Tizen SDK already comes with a jQuery distribution, e.g. [here](https://dzone.com/articles/definitive-guide-developing#SECTION00050000000000000000):

> the Tizen Web Framework incorporates a custom themed jQuery Mobile installation

But its never said how to actually *add* this jQuery installation to my Tizen web app project. Sure, I can download my own distribution and put it into my project folder; but as far as I understand, that's not what the SDK intends.

[Some other sources](http://denvycom.com/blog/how-to-add-gestures-tap-swipe-to-your-gear-2-app/) say that we should use the "jQuery Template" from *File/Tizen Wearable Web Project/Template/Basic*. But **there is no such template** in the current SDK:

[image: There is no "jQuery" template.]

**Question:** How to add the jQuery (Mobile) installation, that comes with the Tizen web framework, to my Tizen web app project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow following steps

1. Open Tizen SDK IDE
2. File -> New Project -> Tizen Web Project
3. **New Tizen Web Project** dialog window will be opened
4. Go to **Sample** tab,
5. Under **Wearable-2.3.1** go to **UI**
6. And Create the **UI Component** sample. And Now explore the UIComponent Project in **Project Explorer**, you can see the **lib** folder. That's the customised the jquery known as **Tizen Advanced UI**(TAU).

---

**Update:** Starting with SDK version 2.3.1, jQuery isn't included any more. So users of SDK version 2.3.1 (and probably higher) should add jQuery manually to their project.

Comment: Okay, so the files are actually there. But when I add `$('.ui-listview').hide();` to `app.js`, e.g. on line 17, right behind the installation of the `tizenhwkey` event listener, the runtime complains: `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: $`

Comment: Ohh I got it. In SDK version 2.3.1, jquery templates are not present. They were present in SDK version 2.3. You can download from here https://developer.tizen.org/sdk

Comment: Alright, thanks for that information :) Any idea how we're supposed to use jQuery with SDK version 2.3.1?

Comment: You can copy your jquery library to your project then include it in your html file.